# Problem subsetting vector from an index that doesn't start from 0

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am getting an error when subsetting a vector from an index that doesn't start from 0. In my code, I want to split to train and test sets. So I subset the first 158 elements for the train set and the last 78 elements for the test set. But the test set refuses to work and gives me a Key Error. Am I missing something obvious, or is there something wrong with the data that I downloaded from the internet as part of the assignment?

```
print(x.shape)
```

out

```
(236L,)
```

It works fine to loop through each element:

```
for i in range(0,236):
    x[i]
```

The train set is working fine:

```
xtr=x[0:158]
for i in range(0,158):
    xtr[i]
```

I cannot subset from an index that doesn't start from 0, giving me Key Error! Perhaps something wrong with my syntax?

```
xts=x[158:]
xts[0]
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-721cd700687d> in <module>()
     13     xtr[i]
     14 xts=x[158:]
---> 15 xts[0]

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.pyc in __getitem__(self, key)
    866         key = com.apply_if_callable(key, self)
    867         try:
--> 868             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
    869 
    870             if not is_scalar(result):

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.pyc in get_value(self, series, key)
   4373         try:
   4374             return self._engine.get_value(s, k,
-> 4375                                           tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
   4376         except KeyError as e1:
   4377             if len(self) > 0 and (self.holds_integer() or self.is_boolean()):

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 0L
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are working with pandas Series here, not python list, that is why it does not work as you expect. `xts[0]` tries to find value `0` within the index of your testing set, but this index seems to start at `158`, so it raises a KeyError.

You can convert your pandas Series to a python list using `x = list(x)`.

If you want to keep using pandas Series, you can access the first element of a Series with `xts.iloc[0]`.